# Why I am getting '0' in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

I am working with the CodeIgniter-4 framework and MySQL database. I am trying to insert form data into the table but only one column (named quantity) value always getting '0'. I checked the values using var_dump and it shows me the right value. But after inserting to the table the value of quantity turns to '0'.

Here is my code:

```
$buyInfo = [
            'productId' => $this->request->getvar('productId'),
            'productName' => $this->request->getvar('productName'),
            'quantity'=>$this->request->getvar('quantity'),
            'unit' => $this->request->getvar('unit'),
            'price' => $this->request->getvar('price'),
            'date'=>$this->request->getvar('date')
           ];

// var_dump($buyInfo); 
// die();
//Here I am getting the right value.
$buyModel->insert($buyInfo);
//After inserting the value of quantity it turns to '0'
```

**Structure of the table:**

[image]

Result of Var_dump

```
array(6) { ["productId"]=> string(1) "3" 
           ["productName"]=> string(4) "Rice" 
           ["quantity"]=> string(3) "102" 
           ["unit"]=> string(2) "kg" 
           ["price"]=> string(4) "1265" 
           ["date"]=> string(10) "2020-05-29" }
```

Comment: Show the var_dump output.

Comment: @Barmar I am added var_dump output. Please take a look on my post again.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but try using `floatval($this->request->getvar('quantity')` to convert the string to a float.

Comment: price and quantity has same structure in the table. If it matters then the price should be shown the same problem as quantity. I tried as you mentioned but it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know code igniter. Is there a way you can see the raw SQL query it's generating?

Comment: do you have any triggers?

Comment: I don't have any triggers. This line `$buyModel->insert($buyInfo);` refers to `INSERT INTO buy (productId,productName, quantity,unit,price,date) VALUES ($productId,$productName, $quantity,$unit,$price,$date)'`

Comment: That can't be right, it's missing quotes around the string values.

Comment: And where are all those variables set? `$buyInfo` is an associative array.

Comment: Try to var_dump `$buyModel->getCompiledInsert($buyInfo);`   It will print your query

Comment: I solved this problem. It was a silly mistake but took my time. I have added an extra space before quantity in my model allowed fields. Thank you for giving me your valuable time.